# Can I move /usr to another partition and create a symbolic link to it?

Tags: ssd, disk-usage, symbolic-link

Someone asked something similar [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846096/why-cant-usr-be-a-symbolic-link), but no one answered, so I will try it.

I've just done a clean reinstall of my system, in which I have a 1TB HDD + 8GB SSD, which was used before for Windows' Fast Boot or something. I formatted it and installed Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 in it, and it works like a charm. Currently I have 1.5 GB of free space in the SSD, and I would like to have more, just in case.

Currently, my somewhat limited Linux knowledge makes me think a good solution for that would be to copy `/usr` or `/usr/share` to another partition and create a symbolic link to it at `/`(root). That's what I've been doing for a few years now with some folders at my home directory, like the Dropbox folder.

Can I do that? If not, why, and what would be a better alternative?

Comment: I've read it, but from my understanding the suggestion is to use a whole partition as `/usr`, and mount it. I would like to have it in a folder somewhere inside the separate partition. I may be confused, though.

Comment: Yes, the suggestion is often to use a whole partition as `/usr` or some of the other system directories, as described also at the following link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: That's probably the best way to go, and I will probably try it. But still, it seems easier to just symlink `/usr`. Right?

Comment: I have not tested symlinking `/usr`. Maybe it works well. If you are willing to test it and share the result, I would be a happy reader/learner :-) It is a good idea to test with a second Ubuntu system (not your main 'production' system).

Comment: Having `/usr` as a symbolic link violates the expectations of directory parenthood of some applications. One example I encountered was the Virtual Box installer when it tried to build the kernel module interface from source (in `/usr/src`).