# How to mount a folder to /usr?

Tags: mount

I'd like to mount a folder on another partition (/dev/sda) named /usr to my local /usr, but I failed.

Here's my attempt:

1. Use a live CD and select try ubuntu.
2. Mount the partition using `sudo mount -s /dev/sda /d`
3. `sudo mkdir /d/usr`, and copy the content to it using `rsync -avH usr /d/usr`
4. remove the original /usr folder `rm -rf usr`
5. add this line to etc/fstab:

`UUID=74e1363e-5493-4522-977f-c267751e9d1a /d              ext4    defaults        0       2`

in which the 74e.... is the uuid of the partition

6. add a symlink using `sudo ln -s /d/usr .`
7. restart the computer.

this doesn't work for me and the computer can't start normally.

how can I solve this and mount a folder to /usr correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Copy everything in your /d/usr folder at the root of your /d partition if it's possible.

Then, instead of using a symlink, you can directly specify the /usr folder as the target mount folder in your fstab:

```
UUID=74e1363e-5493-4522-977f-c267751e9d1a /usr              ext4    defaults        0       2
```

You can refer to [why can't /usr be a symbolic link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846096/why-cant-usr-be-a-symbolic-link) on how to mount a folder in an already mounted partition.

Comment: so /usr can't be a symbolic link right? then that's why I failed. I may need to use that mount -o option right?

Comment: I think so, never tried it though. Check how to use the bind parameter directly in the fstab file here: https://serverfault.com/questions/613179/how-do-i-do-mount-bind-in-etc-fstab

Comment: I done a little bit of testing and I do think this can work, I'm restarting my computer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, you can mount bind folders in fstab using

`/olddir /newdir none bind`

this is a reference to the manpages.

thanks for musinux for telling me about binding.